# How to add receiver address to my contact form

Tags: php, html, forms, post, contacts

How to add receiver address to my contact form. I tried and searched a lot but i cant solve the issue by myself. help! Thx!!!

```
<article id="contact">
    <h2 class="major">Contact</h2>
    <form name="contactform" method="post" action="index.html">
        <div class="fields">
            <div class="field half">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
            </div>
            <div class="field half">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
            </div>
            <div class="field half">
                <label for="email">Telefon</label>
                <input type="text" name="telefon" id="email" />
            </div>
            <div class="field half">
                <label for="email">Subject</label>
                <input type="text" name="subject" id="email" />
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="message">Message</label>
                <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="4"></textarea>          
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="actions">
            <li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="primary"/></li>
            <li><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</article>
```

Comment: Please remove unused idents. Where is your PHP code?

Comment: fyi, `id` attributes need to be unique, your `input`s all have an `id="email"`. Also, check the `for` attributes in your labels. What are you having problems with?

Comment: @MarkusZeller thats the problem! I dont know how to write php. Can you help me?

Comment: @kerbholz i have problems with the receiver mail address. I dont kno how to make it work. The website is a template but unfortunately without a php code for the contact form. so i cant use the form.  I dont know how to write php!

Answer (score 0):

Receiver mailId add at php side, you can pass receiver mailId as "to" filed in php mail function.
    `mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);`
If you implement your sending mail in other way then send your php code

Comment: Thank you much for your answer. Can you explain a bit more for me?
I dont know how to write php. Can you help me?

Comment: ok sure, above your contact form is in html file or in php file ?
so base on your answer, i will provide code

Comment: The website is a HTML page. Thank you a lot for your help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your action in form element 
    `<form name="contactform" method="post" action="some_php_page.php">`

and in some_php_page.php you need to add bellow code.
    
    `if(isset($_Post['name']){
         $to = "Receiver Email Id ";
         $subject = "Your Subject";
         $name = trim($_POST['name']);
         $email = $_Post['email'];
         $telefon = $_Post['telefon'];
         $subject = $_Post['subject'];
         $message = $_Post['message'];
         $body = "Name: ".$name.'\n';
         $body .= "Email: ".$email.'\n';
         $body .= "Subject: ".$subject.'\n';
         $body .= "Message: ".$message.'\n';
         mail($to,$subject,$body);
     }`

Hope this will help you...

Comment: Thanks, i will try it!

Comment: and in some_php_page.php you need to add bellow code. `if(isset($_Post['name']){
What is " `if(isset($_Post['name']){" ?

Comment: Do i have to copy your code into the <body> of the .php file? Or where? Because your code is white, no function. I do something wrong again.... Do i have to put this php code into the index.html page??

Comment: When i try, it says: 

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: you need to 1st create some php file & put my php code directly in it, here i just do some basic coding you may improve it further.
And what ever file name you give to your php file, Need to pass as action in html form as i mention in my answer

Comment: <body> ... </body></html> Like that?

Comment: No.. php is different kind of language, please remove body tag and other html tags and try again..

Comment: I put it in head, in body, everwhere, it never works. I passed the file name of the php file to the action in the html file already.

Comment: Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: I will find another completed contact form. thx for your help anyway!!!

Comment: This if(isset($_Post['name']){
         $to = "Receiver Email Id ";
         $subject = "Your Subject";
         $name = trim($_POST['name']);
         $email = $_Post['email'];
         $telefon = $_Post['telefon'];
         $subject = $_Post['subject'];
         $message = $_Post['message'];
         $body = "Name: ".$name.'\n';
         $body .= "Email: ".$email.'\n';
         $body .= "Subject: ".$subject.'\n';
         $body .= "Message: ".$message.'\n';
         mail($to,$subject,$body);
     } code you need to add in newly created php file which u pass in action